# Supress Lint Warnings : StyleLint SCSS

Tags: css, lint, stylelint

I new to linting in scss file, I have a angular project with following scss file

```
p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

::ng-deep .expandButton {
  margin: 10px;
  color: teal;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

a.mat-list-item.ng-tns-c1-0.active {
  background : #eff0f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  border-right: 3px solid teal;
}
```

and a **.yml** file for lint rules,

```
rules:
  declaration-no-important: null  
  scss/at-rule-no-unknown: null
```

while building the code or executing the following command  `stylelint **.scss`, I'm getting the following errors,

```
 1:1  ×  Unknown rule at-rule-disallowed-list                     at-rule-disallowed-list
 1:1  ×  Unknown rule declaration-property-value-disallowed-list  declaration-property-value-disallowed-list
```

How to fix/suppress this warning, the build passes, there are no errors, but these two lines, keep on occurring for all the scss files.

Comment: I experience this issue as well, whether I specify values for these rules or not.

The linter tells me the `at-rule-disallowed-list` looks for an `Array` and the `declaration-property-value-disallowed-list` takes an `Object`.

Answer (score 6):

The `Unknown rule <rule-name>` error is shown when stylelint encounters a rule in the configuration object that it does not recognise.

The `at-rule-disallowed-list` and `declaration-property-value-disallowed-list` rules were [added to stylelint in version `13.7.0`](https://stylelint.io/changelog#1370).

You can fix these errors by either:

- updating your stylelint to at least version `13.7.0`
- removing the rules from your configuration object